# Can't build docker project with multiple node containers - TravisCI

Tags: docker, dockerfile, travis-ci

I have a pretty simple setup with a node.js endpoint running express, a react app and an nginx server acting as a gateway for the two. I setup dockerfiles for them as follows:

client:

```
FROM node:alpine as builder

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
EXPOSE 3000
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

endpoint:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

nginx:

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

That works pretty well and I can docker-compose without issues to run locally. Now I wanted to setup automatic builds for it on Travis using the following travis.yml:

```
sudo: required
services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - docker build -t personal-page/client-test -f ./client/Dockerfile.dev ./client

script:
  - docker run personal-page/client-test npm test -- --coverage

after_success:
  - docker build -t personal-page/client ./client
  - docker build -t personal-page/endpoint ./endpoint
  - docker build -t personal-page/nginx ./nginx
  # Log in to the docker CLI
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_ID" --password-stdin
  # Push images to docker hub
  - docker push personal-page/client
  - docker push personal-page/endpoint
  - docker push personal-page/nginx
```

But Travis stubbornly throws:
- Build config file is required via repository settings, but config is empty.

I have the environment variables configured and all the paths are correct. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is going to be hilarious but in case someone runs into this. The configuration is all ok and works as intended. The thing is, I had a separate folder on the repository in which I placed all of the individual services in their own folders alongside travis.yml and docker-compose at the top level.

The travis.yml must be however placed at the root directory of the repo. If its down in any underlying folder travis will throw: Build config file is required via repository settings, but config is empty.